# outlook: respond to email and add my comment in the middle of text in the thread

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to be able to respond to outlook email and in the middle of the original text in the thread below , add my comments like

[John Doe] we created the proc

...

[John Doe] Database failed..

I have seen this done before...

Any ideas...

Comment: It's what google wave was made for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck.  Outlook does this already. :)

- Tools | Options (menu)
- E-mail Options (button)
- Mark my comments with: (checkbox)
- "John Doe" (edit box)